# Десериализация объекта содержащего ImageIcon

Tags: java

Имеется следующий класс

```
public class Man implements Serializable{
    private HashMap <String,String>manMap;
    private ArrayList<Relative>relatives;
    private ImageIcon image;

    public ImageIcon getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(ImageIcon image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getManMap() {
        return manMap;
    }

    public void setManMap(HashMap<String, String> manMap) {
        this.manMap = manMap;
    }

    public ArrayList<Relative> getRelatives() {
        return relatives;
    }

    public void setRelatives(ArrayList<Relative> relatives) {
        this.relatives = relatives;
    }

    private class Relative
    {
        String stepenRodstva;
        String family;
        String name;
        String fatherName;
        String dataRozhdenia;
        String osnovanie;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String result=this.stepenRodstva+" - "+this.family+" "+this.name+" "+this.fatherName+", "+dataRozhdenia+" г.р.";
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что когда поле ImageIcon image принимает какое-либо значение, то класс сериализуется, но при десириализации появляется следующая ошибка:

> java.io.InvalidClassException: model.Man; local class incompatible:
>   stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 6154109234569074007, local class
>   serialVersionUID = 8310868017795585876    at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
>     at model.FileSystemModel.manLoader(FileSystemModel.java:35)     at
>   view.StartPage$MenuListener.actionPerformed(StartPage.java:213)

Подскажите в чем проблема.

Comment: Сделайте лучше свой десериализатор, например в JSON, а это поле кладите в Base64 кодировке

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас не совпадают serialVersionUID при десериализации.

Comment: Что это означает?

Comment: @Александр если у вас в классе при сериализации статическое поле "serialsVersionUID" имеет одно значение, а при десериализации - другое.

Comment: Извиняюсь конечно, но как это может получится?

Comment: @Александр, допустим, есть класс Man со статическим полем "serialVersionUID = 6154109234569074007". Вы создаете объект и записываете его в файл. Затем меняете статическое поле на  8310868017795585876. Открываете файл и пытаетесь прочитать объект. В таком случае будет именно такая ошибка, которая есть сейчас у вас.